# Fields from pushed view controller are nil

Tags: swift

I have two view controllers, one has a table view and the second has a label and a image view. Id like to pass the data from the table view cell to the label and image view. In my `didSelectRowAt` function when I try to pass the data, I get thrown the error **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping**. In the debug console, I can see many variables and fields are **nil**. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
    
    if  (searchActive == true) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SongTableViewCell
        cell.mainLabel!.text = songs[indexPath.row].songname
        cell.secondLabel!.text = songs[indexPath.row].artistName
        cell.cellImage!.image = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row].cover)
        return cell
       } else {
       searchActive = true
       }
       return UITableViewCell();
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    
    let songName = songs[indexPath.row].name
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(songName)"
    print(fileURLString)
    Player.shared.playStream(fileUrl: fileURLString)
    let SvC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SongPlayerViewController") as! SongPlayerViewController
    
    SvC.songNames.text = songs[indexPath.row].cleanName //CRASH
    SvC.songCover.image = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row].cover)
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SvC, animated: true)
    
}
```

Comment: It difficult to say why did your app crash without looking into the complete code. Try to check if SvC holds a viewController or not. Use proper breakpoints for this

Comment: Why instantiate a view controller in `didSelectRowAt`? That makes little sense to me - particularly from a storyboard. Your tableView has a data source and the indexPath is giving you all you need at this point. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

Pass only image and text in didSelect method don't try to set in that method. Instead of set direct image and text make variable in second VC and pass value in that variable like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    
    let songName = songs[indexPath.row].name
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(songName)"
    print(fileURLString)
    Player.shared.playStream(fileUrl: fileURLString)
    let SvC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SongPlayerViewController") as! SongPlayerViewController
    
    SvC.var_songNames = songs[indexPath.row].cleanName
    SvC.var_songCover = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row].cover)
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SvC, animated: true)
    
}
```

In your Second Vc define two variable like below

```
var var_songNames: String?
var var_songCover: UIImage?
```

and in second VC

> viewdidload

set value like

```
songNames.text = var_songNames
```